# how to fill out the form initial data?

Tags: python, django

please help with the form is first loaded in the form fields display data from a database.

models:

```
class Status(models.Model):     
    status = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, )     
    @classmethod
    def get_status_list(self):
        status_list = list()
        status_list.append(('', 'no selected'))
        for values_ins in Status.objects.all().values_list('id', 'status'):
            status_list.append(values_ins)
        return status_list              

class UserProfile(User):            
    name1 = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=30,  blank=True, null=True,  )
    name2 = models.CharField('Отчество',    max_length=30,  blank=True, null=True,  )
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status,  verbose_name='Статус',  blank=True, null=True,  )
```

forms:

```
class PersonalDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    status = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=Status.get_status_list(),label='Статус',required=False, )       
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('name1', 'name2', )
```

views:

```
@login_required
def personal_data_page(request):
    entry_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_ptr_id=request.user.id)
    form = PersonalDataForm(instance=entry_user_profile)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonalDataForm(request.POST, instance=entry_user_profile)
        if form.is_valid():         
            form.save() 
            entry_user_profile.save()   
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/userprofile/personal_data_page_changed/')             

    t = loader.get_template('personal_data_page.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {'form': form,})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

template:

```
{{ form.name1 }}
{{ form.name2 }}
{{ form.status }}
```

the problem is that the form is first loaded the user can see the data from the database in the fields: "name1", "name2". but does not see the data from the database in the "status" (it shows a point "no selected", but must show the item corresponding to the value in the table UserProfile.status_id)

I need to when you first load the form in the "status" indicated a certain value. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a model form but then you have override the status field in your form so you need to set the initial value manually by overriding the `__init__` method (one way of doing it, it can be done in other ways also):

```
class PersonalDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    status = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select,
        choices=Status.get_status_list(),
        label='Статус',
        required=False
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PersonalDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["status"].initial = self.instance.status.id # this line sets the value

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('name1', 'name2', )
```

Following are some improvements for your other pieces of code.

Simplified `get_status_list` method:

```
@classmethod
def get_status_list(self):
    status_list = Status.objects.all().values_list('id', 'status')
    status_list.insert(0, ('', 'no selected'))
    return status_list
```

You don't need to have `entry_user_profile.save()` after `form.save()`. The form [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method will return the updated the profile instance by default. So following two lines:

```
form.save() 
entry_user_profile.save()
```

Simplified as:

```
entry_user_profile = form.save()
```

Comment: thanks. but entry_user_profile = form.save() dont save values(